# How to call # from program in android

Tags: android

I want to do this for my school project I want call from my app to show imei number so I want # also to be copied to phone call.But when I am executing the below code only the * is copied to phone call area

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "*#06#"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to call USDD codes you have to use something like this :

```
String code = "*" + Uri.encode("#") + "06" + Uri.encode("#");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + code)));
```

and don't forget to use the call permission in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: This is a better solution because it actually explained the problem with the character @manobromno